# No rule to make target 'proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./cocos2d.cpp'

Tags: eclipse, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have development few games but when i start building a new game i am facing the error for android on eclipse. The project is working fine on xcode but not on eclipe. Now even all my other projects is giving the same error, which was working fine a day ago.

> make: *** No rule to make target
>   `/Users/king/Documents/cocoGamesBeta/game1/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/./cocos2d.cpp',
>   needed by`obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dx_static/cocos2d.o'. 
>   Stop. game1           C/C++ Problem

Thanks,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This kind of errors comes from not writing the definition of functions in cpp class or not adding listener functions callback in cpp.

I resolved it by debugging.

Comment: Impossible: `make` have no idea about definitions, functions, callbacks, classes, and even cpp. The way you have accidentally solved your problem is clean project + rebuild project or something similar. See [GNU Make (wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29)